# Closed form of the $n$-th term of the sequence $1,1,2,4,8,\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What will be the $n$-th term of the sequence defined by

> $$s_1=s_2=1, s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k?$$

Is there any closed formula?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's rather funny that  in this case, $s_n = 2^{n - 2}$, a very nice closed form indeed. Can be proven by induction, for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Good recipe in cases like this: calculate the first 4 or 5 and make a guess. Then try to prove it with induction.

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** We have \begin{align}s_n &= s_1+s_2+\ldots+s_{n-2}+s_{n-1}\\ s_{n-1} &= s_1+s_2+\ldots+s_{n-2}\end{align}

and thus $s_n = 2s_{n-1},\ n\geq 3$. Disregarding $s_1$, can you tell what special kind of sequence this is?